# pdfmake Insert Page Break in table rows

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdfmake

I am using [pdfmake](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/) for generating an organizational document which includes lots of employee information of different groups. I want to insert a page break when new group starts. But here two page breaks are being added.

In the screenshot you can see page number 3 is being added which I want to get rid of.
[image: Screenshots of Demo-Document]

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var demo_document = {
    pageOrientation: "landscape",
    pageMargins: [40, 80, 40, 40],
    header: function(currentPage, pageCount) {
      return [{
          text: "Company Name",
          bold: true,
          fontSize: 14,
          alignment: "center",
          margin: [0, 25, 0, 0],
        },
        {
          text: "Address: House, Road, City, Country",
          alignment: "center",
        },
      ];
    },
    footer: function(currentPage, pageCount) {
      return [{
        text: "Page " + currentPage.toString() + " of " + pageCount.toString(),
        alignment: "center",
      }, ];
    },
    content: [{
      table: {
        widths: ["auto", "*", "*", "auto", "*"],
        headerRows: 1,
        dontBreakRows: true,
        body: [
          [{
              text: "ID",
              style: "columnHeader"
            },
            {
              text: "Name",
              style: "columnHeader"
            },
            {
              text: "Designation",
              style: "columnHeader"
            },
            {
              text: "Salary",
              style: "columnHeader"
            },
            {
              text: "Remarks",
              style: "columnHeader"
            },
          ],
          [{
              text: "First Group",
              colSpan: 5,
            },
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
          ],
          [{
            text: "01"
          }, {
            text: "AA"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "02"
          }, {
            text: "BB"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "03"
          }, {
            text: "CC"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "04"
          }, {
            text: "DD"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "05"
          }, {
            text: "EE"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "06"
          }, {
            text: "FF"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "07"
          }, {
            text: "GG"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "08"
          }, {
            text: "HH"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "09"
          }, {
            text: "II"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "10"
          }, {
            text: "JJ"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "11"
          }, {
            text: "KK"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "12"
          }, {
            text: "LL"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "13"
          }, {
            text: "MM"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "14"
          }, {
            text: "NN"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "15"
          }, {
            text: "OO"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "16"
          }, {
            text: "PP"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "17"
          }, {
            text: "QQ"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "18"
          }, {
            text: "RR"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "19"
          }, {
            text: "SS"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "20"
          }, {
            text: "TT"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "21"
          }, {
            text: "UU"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "22"
          }, {
            text: "VV"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "23"
          }, {
            text: "WW"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "24"
          }, {
            text: "XX"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "25"
          }, {
            text: "YY"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "26"
          }, {
            text: "ZZ"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
              text: "",
              colSpan: 5,
              pageBreak: "before",
            },
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
          ],
          [{
              text: "Second Group",
              colSpan: 5,
            },
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
          ],
          [{
            text: "27"
          }, {
            text: "AB"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "28"
          }, {
            text: "BC"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "29"
          }, {
            text: "CD"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "30"
          }, {
            text: "DE"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "31"
          }, {
            text: "EF"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "32"
          }, {
            text: "FG"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "33"
          }, {
            text: "GH"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "34"
          }, {
            text: "HI"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "35"
          }, {
            text: "IJ"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "36"
          }, {
            text: "JK"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "37"
          }, {
            text: "KL"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "38"
          }, {
            text: "LM"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "39"
          }, {
            text: "MN"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "40"
          }, {
            text: "NO"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "41"
          }, {
            text: "OP"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "42"
          }, {
            text: "PQ"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "43"
          }, {
            text: "QR"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "44"
          }, {
            text: "RS"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "45"
          }, {
            text: "ST"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "46"
          }, {
            text: "TU"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "47"
          }, {
            text: "UV"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "48"
          }, {
            text: "VW"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "49"
          }, {
            text: "WX"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "50"
          }, {
            text: "XY"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "51"
          }, {
            text: "YZ"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
          [{
            text: "52"
          }, {
            text: "ZA"
          }, {
            text: "Officer"
          }, {
            text: "1000"
          }, {
            text: ""
          }],
        ],
      },
      layout: {
        hLineWidth: function(i, node) {
          return i === 0 || i === node.table.body.length ? 1 : 0.5;
        },
        vLineWidth: function(i, node) {
          return i === 0 || i === node.table.widths.length ? 1 : 0.5;
        },
        hLineColor: function(i, node) {
          return "#777777";
        },
        vLineColor: function(i, node) {
          return "#777777";
        },
      },
    }, ],
    styles: {
      columnHeader: {
        bold: true,
        alignment: "center",
      },
    },
  };

  pdfMake.createPdf(demo_document).getDataUrl(function(frontSource) {
    document.getElementById("demo-document").src = frontSource;
  });
});
```

```css
.container .row .col-12 .embed-responsive .embed-responsive-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row border m-1">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 text-center">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="demo-document"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.72/pdfmake.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.72/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I remove extra page break?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just facing the same problem.
My workaround is to remove the `dontBreakRows` flag.
The downside to this is that on every new page forced by `pageBreak` there is a small empty row at the top.

```
 var dd = {
    pageOrientation: "landscape",
    content: [{ 
          table: {
            widths: ["auto", "*"],
            headerRows: 1,
            //keepWithHeaderRows: true,
            //dontBreakRows: true,
            body: [
              [
                  { text: "ID"},
                  { text: "Name"}
              ],
              [
                  { text: "01" },
                  { text: "AA" }
              ],
              [
                  { text: "", pageBreak:"after" },
                  { text: "" }
              ],
              [
                  {text: "27"},
                  {text: "AB"}
              ]
            ],
          }
    }],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the second group as another table and page break on the second table object.

Modified document definitions:

```
var dd = {
      pageOrientation: "landscape",
      pageMargins: [40, 80, 40, 40],
      header: function(currentPage, pageCount) {
        return [{
            text: "Company Name",
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 14,
            alignment: "center",
            margin: [0, 25, 0, 0],
          },
          {
            text: "Address: House, Road, City, Country",
            alignment: "center",
          },
        ];
      },
      footer: function(currentPage, pageCount) {
        return [{
          text: "Page " + currentPage.toString() + " of " + pageCount.toString(),
          alignment: "center",
        }, ];
      },
      content: [{
        table: {
          widths: ["auto", "*", "*", "auto", "*"],
          headerRows: 1,
          dontBreakRows: true,
          body: [
            [{
                text: "ID",
                style: "columnHeader"
              },
              {
                text: "Name",
                style: "columnHeader"
              },
              {
                text: "Designation",
                style: "columnHeader"
              },
              {
                text: "Salary",
                style: "columnHeader"
              },
              {
                text: "Remarks",
                style: "columnHeader"
              },
            ],
            [{
                text: "First Group",
                colSpan: 5,
              },
              {},
              {},
              {},
              {},
            ],
            [{
              text: "01"
            }, {
              text: "AA"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "02"
            }, {
              text: "BB"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "03"
            }, {
              text: "CC"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "04"
            }, {
              text: "DD"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "05"
            }, {
              text: "EE"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "06"
            }, {
              text: "FF"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "07"
            }, {
              text: "GG"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "08"
            }, {
              text: "HH"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "09"
            }, {
              text: "II"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "10"
            }, {
              text: "JJ"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "11"
            }, {
              text: "KK"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "12"
            }, {
              text: "LL"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "13"
            }, {
              text: "MM"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "14"
            }, {
              text: "NN"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "15"
            }, {
              text: "OO"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "16"
            }, {
              text: "PP"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "17"
            }, {
              text: "QQ"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "18"
            }, {
              text: "RR"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "19"
            }, {
              text: "SS"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "20"
            }, {
              text: "TT"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "21"
            }, {
              text: "UU"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "22"
            }, {
              text: "VV"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "23"
            }, {
              text: "WW"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "24"
            }, {
              text: "XX"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "25"
            }, {
              text: "YY"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "26"
            }, {
              text: "ZZ"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000",
              
            }, {
              text: "",
            }],
          ],
        },
        layout: {
          hLineWidth: function(i, node) {
            return i === 0 || i === node.table.body.length ? 1 : 0.5;
          },
          vLineWidth: function(i, node) {
            return i === 0 || i === node.table.widths.length ? 1 : 0.5;
          },
          hLineColor: function(i, node) {
            return "#777777";
          },
          vLineColor: function(i, node) {
            return "#777777";
          },
        },
      },
      
      {
        pageBreak: 'before',
        table: {
          widths: ["auto", "*", "*", "auto", "*"],
          headerRows: 1,
          dontBreakRows: true,
          body: [
              [{
                text: "ID",
                style: "columnHeader"
              },
              {
                text: "Name",
                style: "columnHeader"
              },
              {
                text: "Designation",
                style: "columnHeader"
              },
              {
                text: "Salary",
                style: "columnHeader"
              },
              {
                text: "Remarks",
                style: "columnHeader"
              },
            ],
              [{
                text: "Second Group",
                colSpan: 5,
              },
              {},
              {},
              {},
              {},
            ],
            [{
              text: "27"
            }, {
              text: "AB"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "28"
            }, {
              text: "BC"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "29"
            }, {
              text: "CD"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "30"
            }, {
              text: "DE"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "31"
            }, {
              text: "EF"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "32"
            }, {
              text: "FG"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "33"
            }, {
              text: "GH"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "34"
            }, {
              text: "HI"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "35"
            }, {
              text: "IJ"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "36"
            }, {
              text: "JK"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "37"
            }, {
              text: "KL"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "38"
            }, {
              text: "LM"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "39"
            }, {
              text: "MN"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "40"
            }, {
              text: "NO"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "41"
            }, {
              text: "OP"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "42"
            }, {
              text: "PQ"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "43"
            }, {
              text: "QR"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "44"
            }, {
              text: "RS"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "45"
            }, {
              text: "ST"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "46"
            }, {
              text: "TU"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "47"
            }, {
              text: "UV"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "48"
            }, {
              text: "VW"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "49"
            }, {
              text: "WX"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "50"
            }, {
              text: "XY"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "51"
            }, {
              text: "YZ"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "52"
            }, {
              text: "ZA"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }]]
        },
        layout: {
          hLineWidth: function(i, node) {
            return i === 0 || i === node.table.body.length ? 1 : 0.5;
          },
          vLineWidth: function(i, node) {
            return i === 0 || i === node.table.widths.length ? 1 : 0.5;
          },
          hLineColor: function(i, node) {
            return "#777777";
          },
          vLineColor: function(i, node) {
            return "#777777";
          },
        },
      }
      ],
      styles: {
        columnHeader: {
          bold: true,
          alignment: "center",
        },
      },
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem was in lines 347 to 365, which created empty objects and caused interference.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var demo_document = {
      pageOrientation: "landscape",
      pageMargins: [40, 80, 40, 40],
      header: function(currentPage, pageCount) {
        return [{
            text: "Company Name",
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 14,
            alignment: "center",
            margin: [0, 25, 0, 0],
          },
          {
            text: "Address: House, Road, City, Country",
            alignment: "center",
          },
        ];
      },
      footer: function(currentPage, pageCount) {
        return [{
          text: "Page " + currentPage.toString() + " of " + pageCount.toString(),
          alignment: "center",
        }, ];
      },
      content: [{
        table: {
          widths: ["auto", "*", "*", "auto", "*"],
          headerRows: 1,
          dontBreakRows: true,
          body: [
            [{
                text: "ID",
                style: "columnHeader"
              },
              {
                text: "Name",
                style: "columnHeader"
              },
              {
                text: "Designation",
                style: "columnHeader"
              },
              {
                text: "Salary",
                style: "columnHeader"
              },
              {
                text: "Remarks",
                style: "columnHeader"
              },
            ],
            [{
                text: "First Group",
                colSpan: 5,
              },
              {},
              {},
              {},
              {},
            ],
            [{
              text: "01"
            }, {
              text: "AA"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "02"
            }, {
              text: "BB"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "03"
            }, {
              text: "CC"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "04"
            }, {
              text: "DD"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "05"
            }, {
              text: "EE"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "06"
            }, {
              text: "FF"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "07"
            }, {
              text: "GG"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "08"
            }, {
              text: "HH"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "09"
            }, {
              text: "II"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "10"
            }, {
              text: "JJ"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "11"
            }, {
              text: "KK"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "12"
            }, {
              text: "LL"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "13"
            }, {
              text: "MM"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "14"
            }, {
              text: "NN"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "15"
            }, {
              text: "OO"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "16"
            }, {
              text: "PP"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "17"
            }, {
              text: "QQ"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "18"
            }, {
              text: "RR"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "19"
            }, {
              text: "SS"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "20"
            }, {
              text: "TT"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "21"
            }, {
              text: "UU"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "22"
            }, {
              text: "VV"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "23"
            }, {
              text: "WW"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "24"
            }, {
              text: "XX"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "25"
            }, {
              text: "YY"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "26"
            }, {
              text: "ZZ"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            // [{
            //     text: "",
            //     colSpan: 5,
            //     pageBreak: "before",
            //   },
            //   {},
            //   {},
            //   {},
            //   {},
            // ],
            // [{
            //     text: "Second Group",
            //     colSpan: 5,
            //   },
            //   {},
            //   {},
            //   {},
            //   {},
            // ],
            [{
              text: "27"
            }, {
              text: "AB"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "28"
            }, {
              text: "BC"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "29"
            }, {
              text: "CD"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "30"
            }, {
              text: "DE"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "31"
            }, {
              text: "EF"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "32"
            }, {
              text: "FG"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "33"
            }, {
              text: "GH"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "34"
            }, {
              text: "HI"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "35"
            }, {
              text: "IJ"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "36"
            }, {
              text: "JK"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "37"
            }, {
              text: "KL"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "38"
            }, {
              text: "LM"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "39"
            }, {
              text: "MN"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "40"
            }, {
              text: "NO"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "41"
            }, {
              text: "OP"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "42"
            }, {
              text: "PQ"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "43"
            }, {
              text: "QR"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "44"
            }, {
              text: "RS"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "45"
            }, {
              text: "ST"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "46"
            }, {
              text: "TU"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "47"
            }, {
              text: "UV"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "48"
            }, {
              text: "VW"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "49"
            }, {
              text: "WX"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "50"
            }, {
              text: "XY"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "51"
            }, {
              text: "YZ"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
            [{
              text: "52"
            }, {
              text: "ZA"
            }, {
              text: "Officer"
            }, {
              text: "1000"
            }, {
              text: ""
            }],
          ],
        },
        layout: {
          hLineWidth: function(i, node) {
            return i === 0 || i === node.table.body.length ? 1 : 0.5;
          },
          vLineWidth: function(i, node) {
            return i === 0 || i === node.table.widths.length ? 1 : 0.5;
          },
          hLineColor: function(i, node) {
            return "#777777";
          },
          vLineColor: function(i, node) {
            return "#777777";
          },
        },
      }, ],
      styles: {
        columnHeader: {
          bold: true,
          alignment: "center",
        },
      },
    };
  
    pdfMake.createPdf(demo_document).getDataUrl(function(frontSource) {
      document.getElementById("demo-document").src = frontSource;
    });
  });
```

```css
.container .row .col-12 .embed-responsive .embed-responsive-item {
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row border m-1">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 text-center">
                    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="demo-document"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.72/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.72/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if you remove those lines then how you add page break?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).